Is there a semisimple abelian category or a split abelian category with an infinite number of simple objects?
An abelian category $\mathcal A$ with arbitrary coproducts (for example, a Grothendieck category) is semisimple if every object in $\mathcal A$ is a coproduct of simple objects. It is true that every semisimple abelian category is a split category, i.e. every short exact sequence splits, but not conversely: namely, there are split categories which are not semisimple. In fact there are spectral categories (Grothendieck and split) which are continuous (i.e. there are no simple objects). See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327899/name-for-abelian-category-in-which-every-short-exact-sequence-splits
My request: an example of an abelian split category (maybe a spectral category), either semisimple or not, with an infinite number of non-isomorphic simple objects.
Furthermore, for any cardinal number $\kappa$, is there an abelian split category such that a set of complete irredundant representatives of isomorphism classes of simple objects has cardinality $\kappa$?

Just take any set $X$ and consider the abelian category of $X$-graded vector spaces. The simple objects are the $1$-dimensional vector spaces supported at some $x \in X$ so there are $|X|$ of them, and this category is semisimple.
For an example which arises in practice but dropping the condition of having arbitrary coproducts you can consider, for example, the category of finite-dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, which is semisimple and has countably many simple objects. (If we drop "finite-dimensional" the resulting category is no longer semisimple.) Variations of this which restore arbitrary coproducts are possible; I believe the Ind-category of this category is the category of representations of the algebraic group $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$.
